# Concept of a concentric-double-slotted axial flux permanent magnet machine (motor)

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, magnetics, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

I am after a design of a permanent magnet machine which is very constrained in the axial direction, but basically unrestricted in radial one. I also need significant space for the shaft hole.

The thought of an axial flux machine is pretty obvious, but what about adding a second row of slots 180 degrees apart:

[image]

Here the red/blue disks are the permanent magnets, the yellow/green/red bricks represent the slots of the three phases, using concentrated winding. The aspect ratio in the radial direction is close to what I intend to achieve.

The scope of the exercise are:

1. Reduce the length of the magnetic circuit by having the phases packed together more closely, and therefore cut the thickness of the yokes (not shown in the picture).
2. Reduce the axial forces on the rotor and the low order vibration modes.
3. Reduce the cogging torque.

Although these (and possibly other) benefits, I have never encountered this topology before, therefore I would like to know if there are any obvious **showstoppers** which I am failing to see. In particular I am very sensitive to losses/efficiency.

---

Here is a minimal configuration which may help to understand the topology. In this case the slot geometry and the winding would likely require separate optimizations for the two circles, but the real case has an aspect ratio much closer to the picture above.

[image]

Comment: Never seen anything quite like it! Can't see a fundamental flaw, but makes me wonder about extending the idea to a 3-ring (circus?) where each ring is a single phase , rotated 120 degrees (1/3 pole) apart, making winding easier.